# How to make horizontal layout of pandoc markdown tables?

Tags: html, latex, markdown, pandoc

[Code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/247003/13173)

```
pandoc                              \
     data.tex                       \
    -f markdown                     \
    -t html                         \
                                    \
| grep -E '(^<|^$|^ *$)'            \
                                    \
| grep -v '^<p'                     \
                                    \
| perl -pe 's#(?<!\\)%.*</#</#'     \
                                    \
| pandoc                            \
    -f html                         \
    -o vertical_output.pdf          \
    --latex-engine=xelatex
```

which gives tables on vertical layout as output, see the picture below.

### Example case where horizontal table is needed

The content of the file *data.tex* is the following data.

Data.tex:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Name            Description     Location        Examples            Start            Peak            Duration        Appearance
--------------- --------------- --------------  ------------------- ---------------- --------------  ---------------  -------------------
Prandial        short-acting    belly,          Lispro (Humalog),   5-10 min before  30-60 minutes   2-4 hours       Transparent
                analogs         abdomen         Aspart (Novorapid), meal
                = chemically                    Glulisine (Apidra)
                sythesized;


Regular/short   human insulin   addomen         Humulin R           30 min before    60 minutes      6-8 hours,       Transparent
                not analog                                          meal                             hypoglycemia
                                                                    not flexible                     risk 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Table: Diabetic drugs parndial and basal. Location, start, peak, duration and appearance.
```

giving by running the above code to the data

[image]

Comments

- I would like to have a horizontal layout such that the table would be adjusted to it. I do not know to which stage I should affect to have it. 
  I think it should be possible in the last pandoc -process.

### Too much space around sparse tables

One document has many types of tables. 
The current accepted answer works well if tables are rather full, but badly with sparse tables. 
Using the parameter of the accepted answer `-V geometry:"paperwidth=22in, paperheight=210mm, margin=2cm"`, we get:

[image]

where the second table is extended too much; I would like to have it narrower; but not sure if this is possible dynamically in Pandoc.

---

How can you have a horizontal layout of pandocing?

Comment: What does your input data look like? It seems to be hosted in file **`data.tex`**. The filename suffix suggests it is (La)TeX. The command line switch **`-f markdown`** tells pandoc to handle that input as Markdown... What gives?

Comment: @KurtPfeifle Example data is in the Example data section in the body of the question, which you can save as *data.tex*.

Comment: Then please make that fact clear by labelling the data as *"Content of `data.tex`"* or similar, not just as "data".

Comment: Again, you added another PDF output table to your illustration without providing the input data which it took to generate it. Please give up any hope you may have that you get any useful answer to such incomplete questions. Please start applying basic logic. Please don't assume your readers know what you know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you use Pandoc to produce PDF output, you can control the page size of the file with an addition to the command line. For example, generate a page with a width of 22 inches and a height of 210 Millimeters, while keeping each margin at 2 Centimeters, use this Pandoc parameter:

```
-V geometry:"paperwidth=22in, paperheight=210mm, margin=2cm"
```

I hope this example makes clear to you how you can influence the output paper size in different other ways.

However, I do not know if it answers your question. Your question is not very clear to me, I must admit.

My answer however may help other people when searching for *"[horizontal layout pandoc markdown](https://www.google.de/search?q=horizontal+layout+pandoc+markdown)"*.

**Full commands to try**

***First, 12 inches width:***

```
pandoc                              \
     data.tex                       \
    -f markdown                     \
    -t html                         \
                                    \
| grep -E '(^<|^$|^ *$)'            \
                                    \
| grep -v '^<p'                     \
                                    \
| perl -pe 's#(?<!\\)%.*</#</#'     \
                                    \
| pandoc                            \
    -f html                         \
    -o vertical_output1.pdf         \
    --latex-engine=xelatex          \
    -V geometry:"paperwidth=12in, paperheight=80mm, margin=0.5cm"
```

***Second, 14 inches width:***

```
pandoc                              \
     data.tex                       \
    -f markdown                     \
    -t html                         \
                                    \
| grep -E '(^<|^$|^ *$)'            \
                                    \
| grep -v '^<p'                     \
                                    \
| perl -pe 's#(?<!\\)%.*</#</#'     \
                                    \
| pandoc                            \
    -f html                         \
    -o vertical_output1.pdf         \
    --latex-engine=xelatex          \
    -V geometry:"paperwidth=14in, paperheight=80mm, margin=0.5cm"
```

**Outputs (as PNG screenshots from the PDFs to make them visible here):**

[image]

[image]

Comment: I extended your answer to conditions where you have full tables and sparse tables, see the body of the question. How can Pandoc handle such tables dynamically? I would like to have narrowed sparse tables.

Comment: Sorry, I don't like it if you "extend" and change my answer too much. I recommend you do the following: ***(1)*** Re-work your original question to make it clear what you want. Because it is not yet clear even to me -- even though you made my answer, which to me was a *"shot into the dark"*, the accepted one.  ***(2)*** Add your own answer with your extension. I will even upvote it, if it does deserve so.  :-)

Comment: This case is done here. I added an extension about the accepted answer which shows a limitation in it. Therefore, a new thread. No point adding here extensions as answers which goes too much side-ways. An output of proposed answers is the least which I expect from answers so I added the output of your command so it is easy to preview it. Improvements here and in the new thread are always welcome! I think the feedback of answers can be very fruitful.